# PHP session - prevent entire page from loading

Tags: php, session

I'm fairly new to back-end programming, and can't seem to find an answer to an easy (in my view) problem. I understand that if I want to display only a specific piece of data for a given user (e.g. items in the cart), I would use a session ID to identify that user and insert whatever information for that specific user from the database into my page through php's ***echo*** function. Now, what if I have a page with a lot of lines of html code and want the code to run only if there's a session? Should I put all that code into ***else {echo "...html code...";}*** and have a page looking something like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('location:../');
        exit();
    } else {
        echo "
            <html>
            <body>
                code
                code
                code
                code
            </body>
            </html> ";
    }
?>
```

This seems to be working, but the whole approach seems very bulky and my gut tells me that's not how I should be preventing each page from loading at all unless the user is signed in. Also, this method creates all sorts of issues with quotes and makes the code really hard to read and debug.

Comment: You don't need the else. That code would never run if the `if` condition is met because the `exit();` terminates the script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
  session_start();    
  if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    header('location:../');
    exit(); // <-- terminates the current script
  }
// close the php tag and write your HTML :)
?>
<html>
  <body>
    code
    code
    <!-- if you need another php tag somewhere else -->
    <?php if(1 != 2) echo '<em>PHP works :)</em>'; ?>
    code
    code
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't it bad form to use exit() in such scripts as it terminates the thread and defeats the purpose of having multi-threaded application servers whose threads can be reused? Unless you're using pure CGI.

Answer (score 0):

Your session I'd will be there whether you recognize the user or not.
You to pass the session id along either through a form variable or through a session cookie.  And the call the session by setting the session id

```
session_id($session_var_passed);
session_start();
```

You should test for the session varaible passed.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do something like this.**

```
<?php

    $shouldShow = 0;
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['id'])){
        $shouldShow = 1;



}
?>
<html>
<body>


<script>

var shouldLoad = <?php echo $shouldShow; ?>;
if (shouldLoad == 1){

    loadPage(true); // load page is an imaginary Javascript function which
            //you can make to load the page.

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this way you mix up php and java-script to reach your goal and make the website more user friendly.

The first php part contains php variable which will be set to 1 if the session exists.

Now you have the HTML part where you have a script tag, under which there is a variable. You simply echo the value of php variable "shouldLoad" into this javascript variable. So now your javascript knows wheather to load or not load the webpage. Make necessary adjustment in your javascript code to load the webpage depending on this value of variable.

**Another way of doing this is.**

```
    <?php


    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])){           
        header('Location: http://myhost.com/mypage.php');
        // redirect the page to another location (a page saying no session found)

}

?>


<html>
<body>
    your html codes you want to show
</body>
</html>
```

Also if you just want to exit your php script and do not care about the cool UI, you can simply put "exit()" inside your 'if' condition so that the script terminates it doesnt find the desired session ID.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, won't you open yourself to a security risk if the header is redirected but there's no exit() after since the server will still attempt to run the entire code? Or does changing header prevents any code below that line from running?

Comment: i have just showed you an example regardless of any security loophole.
Yes definitely, header is only a line of data asking the browser to redirect but if it doesnt redirects in time or the client manages to skip, the codes still execute. Better to use exit or die after header or add another line of protection code before serving the html.

Comment: @phositronax this code can easily be hacked in the developer tools console by changing var shouldLoad to 1 manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if you think page is too bulky

```
<?php
    session_start();    
    if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
        header('yourFile.php);
        exit();

}
```

"your file.php"

```
<?php
     echo "
                <html>
                <body>
                    code
                    code
                    code
                    code
                </body>
                </html> ";
     ?>
```